# Intuition/Derivation for Newton's Sums?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I often come across problems in which I want to find the sum of the $k$'th powers of the roots of a polynomial. I have heard of a method known as the Newton-Girardae formulae. However, I cannot understand any explanations of them. Could someone provide intuition and derivation for the Newton Sum identities, without using calculus or abstract algebra?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Newton sum method is based on obtaining a linear recurrence relation with help of product of roots taken 'n' at a time at a time, that gives us the power sum of roots.
A very easy explaination is given [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/).